# Existence of a locally essentially unbounded integrable function

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, geometric-measure-theory

Does there exist an integrable function $f\colon [0,1]\to \mathbb{R}_+$ such that for every $0\leq a < b\leq 1$ we have $\| \chi_{(a,b)} f\|_\infty = + \infty$?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @T.Bongers put me out of my misery with a reference please!

Comment: So take a one to one function $\lambda \colon \mathbb{Q}\to \mathbb N$. For each $q\in \mathbb{Q}$ let $f_q$ be the function that is continuous except at $q$, infinite at $q$, and with integral $1$. Now take the function $g=\sum_{q} 1/2^{\lambda(q)} f_q$. This is the desired function. Thanks

Comment: Here is a very easy solution: Take your favorite nonnegative integrable function $f$ and change it on rational numbers $q$ so that $f(q)$ is the denominator of the representation of $q$ as a fraction in lowest terms.